# Replace text between 2 strings in bash with result of ls

Tags: bash, awk

I want to create an automation for a deployment, the js/css are generated with a prefix and I want to import them in the php file between the tags

*Expected Output*

```
...
/*bashStart*/
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path("module","myModule")."/styles/c91c6d11.main.css");
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module","myModule")."/scripts/j91c6d11.main.js");
/*bashEnd*/
...
```

I used awk and got me here so far but I have a problem, it's generating

```
    ...
    /*bashStart*/
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path("module","myModule")."/styles/c91c6d11.main.css
");
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module","myModule")."/scripts/j91c6d11.main.js
");
    /*bashEnd*/
    ...
```

here is the awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN {p=1}/Start/{print;printf("drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path(\"module\",\"myModule\").\"/styles/");system("ls styles");printf("\");\n");printf("drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path(\"module\",\"myModule\").\"/scripts/");system("ls scripts");printf("\");\n");p=0}/Finish/{p=1} p' myModule.module > tmp;
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what is the given input and the exact desired output?

Comment: @fedorqui basically the input doesn't really matter, the difference I have from the expected output is a new line after each drupal_add

Comment: Well what I mean is that we need some kind of input data to be able to test your awk command :)

Comment: @fedorqui for input you could make a file with lots of lorem ipsum lines and at some point add /*bashStart*/ testing  /*bashEnd*/

Comment: You should definitely read the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specially when it says _"Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"_.

Comment: I though 'import them in the php file between the tags' was clear since the content of the file are not important when you need only to insert 2 lines between 2 tag lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ls within awk isn't very nice - I think you can do this entirely in the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

p=1
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line = '/*bashEnd*/' ]] && p=1
    (( p )) && echo "$line"
    if [[ $line = '/*bashStart*/' ]]; then
        p=0
        for style in styles/*; do
            echo 'drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path("module","myModule")."/styles/'"$style"'");'
        done
        for script in scripts/*; do
            echo 'drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module","myModule")."/scripts/'"$script"'");'
        done
    fi
done < file.php > output.php
```

Loop through the input file until you reach the "bashStart" line, then add the lines you want. Output goes to a file `output.php` which you can check before overwriting the original file. If you're feeling confident you can add `&& mv output.php file.php` to the `done` line, to overwrite the original file.

The flag `p` controls which lines are printed. It is set to 0 when the "bashStart" line is reached and back to 1 when the bashEnd line is reached, so lines between the two are replaced.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, also the contents of the file will not change on each deployment so it's important to replace data between the 2 tags because if you run this many times it will simply append the new lines after the bashStart tag

Comment: @Stefanos I've made a slight modification that should cause the lines in between the tags to be overwritten

Comment: Thanks it's perfect, the reason it wasn't working at all in the first time was that the file should have linux line endings